# Discord bot won't join channel and play music

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I've been following a guide on how to set it up. But I changed somethings about how the setup is and some other additions. These are the only changes that I've made. I don't have enough experience when it comes to Javascript/node.js. I've gone through a lot of videos when it comes to giving the bot permissions, and I think I got that part right.

When running a command it just shows up as "!play [link]" in Powershell. The bot runs fine when running other "basic" commands.

Link to tutorial - https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot

Link to project - https://github.com/OriginalMHV/projects

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = ('./config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`)
} )

const queue = new Map();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file package.json, the main file is index.js, but no file exists with that name, I suppose the main file is bot.js, but it is in another directory and the name is not the same.

Comment: I suggest to remove the token from your repository as soon as possible (file configure.json). It might be used to control the server where the bot is.

Comment: I thought I removed it, it's changed now. Thanks :) 

Still a problem with not connecting to a channel. Changed the package.json "main" to "/src/bot.js".

Comment: I can’t find any problem in your code, try to create a new project copying all the code directly from the tutorial. If this work, there might be a library problem with your current one. If that doesn’t work, I don’t know what to suggest.

Comment: I tried to create a new project and only getting the "music" part of the bot. Sadly it does not work. I'm kinda lost on how to fix it, but thanks for the help :)